# Add to collection if not already available with linq

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a collection in C# which stores data of persons. 
Now i want to update the collections list. 
Before i update any object in the list i want to check if the person already exists. All persons have 9 proporties. I want to check by two properties if the stored data is already in the collection.

If the person already exist, i want to drop the old data and want to save all properties from the new one.
If the person not exist, i want to create a new object with the new data.
New data i read from a external file and save it to the collection list.
Old data is stored in a xml file and i load it to the collection list.

My approach so far:

Add new person to list, even its available. Then delete duplicates and halt persons which are later added to list.

or

before adding select with linq by `person.name` and `person.sname` and set all properties by the new data, if not exists create new one.

```
List<person> with {name, sname, mobile, email, adress1, adress2, fone, age, gender}

 List<person> list = new List<person>;
 Person person = new Person();
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(XMLPath);

 // somethink like that
 list.Select(list.Name && list.sName)
 where ...
```

I am new with linq so i had problems to realize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the solution depends on quite a few things you are no specifying. Is `Person` mutable? If it is, the solution is pretty straightforward:

```
List<Person> persons = ....
var specificPerson = perons.Where(p => p.Name == something && p.Age == somethingElse).FirstOrDefault();

if (specificPerson != null) //We have a person in the list (I'm assuming Person is a class, not struct)
{
    specificPerson.Name = updatedValue;
    specificPerson.Age = someOtherUpdatedValue;ç
    // etc.
}
else //Person is not in the list
{
    var newPerson = new Person( /*new data*/ );
    persons.Add(newPerson);
}
```

If `Person` is immutable, then you want to remove completely the existing `Person` and create a new one:

```
List<Person> persons = ....
var specificPerson ? Perons.Where( p => p.Name == something && p.Age == somethingElse).FirstOrDefault();

if (specificPerson != null)
{
    persons.Remove(specificPerson);
}

var newPerson = new Person( /*new data*/ );
persons.Add(newPerson);
```

Comment: That was it, thank a lot! i used a foreach to loop over the first list and compare the properties.

Comment: How can i compare name and sname if both are string. i tried Equals and Contains both with an exception? (NullRefernceException)

Comment: get it with adding try catch

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
list.AsEnumerable().Select(person => ((person.name.Equals(toAdd.name) && person.sName.Equals(toAdd.sName))) ? toAdd : person);
```

Basically, you select all those that have the `name` and `sname` that you want and replace them with `toAdd`(which is the `Person` you want to add). If the selected item doesn't fit the criteria, then it's not replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your approach!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use lambda for selecting a person

```
Person person = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == "NameToAdd" && p.sname == "SNameToAdd");
```

You can also use SingleOrDefault instead if you are sure that only one such element should exist in a collection. FirstOrDefault/SingleOrDefault will return a person or null if it won't find anything matching passed in criteria

Comment: Thank you for your solution!